# Почему в JSON, возвращенном от VK API, присутствуют несоответствия?

Tags: json, vkontakte-api

Почему после вызова метода users.search апи возвращает JSON, в котором в поле count стоит 4, но в поле items всего 3 пользователя?

Comment: Пример того, что вернул API можете привести? Какой запросы вы выполняли?

Comment: Пример: https://imgur.com/eKb2rID, запрос обычный user.search с полями q и birth_year, дело в том, что из веб-интерфейса вк при аналогичном запросе выводится 4 человека, да и в JSON response в count 4, но в items всего 3 профиля, почему возвращаются не все профили, может кто-нибудь знает